# Equations not centered

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations

I have searched this forum, but could not find the solution.

I have the below equations but they are not centered. I would need them centered. Please help if you can.

Code:

```
\begin{ceqn}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\dot{x}= Ax + Bu \\
y = Cx
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
\end{ceqn}
```

Output (desired output to be centered):

[image]

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Normally, `equation*` is centred. Why do you use the `ceqn` environment?

Comment: The word "align" in the name of the `align*` and `aligned` environments should be a strong hint that they can (and should be used to) perform various forms of alignment. If *no alignment* is desired, don't use `align*` or `aligned`. Instead, use `gather*` and `gathered`.

Comment: Unfortunatelly I am a beginner, so took the examples from other posts. But now I cleared my code and it works perfectly. Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is not very clear. Maybe this code does what you want?

```
\begin{gather*}
\dot{x}= Ax + Bu \\
y = Cx
\end{gather*}
```